# MS graph API query fails with Plus sign

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api

Using MS graph API I can query a user account using their id value and it works fine.

Issue - when using MS graph API I can query a user account using their username (which has a + sign) it fails.

This works fine.

```
curl --location 'https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?%24filter=id%20eq%20%278159db30-d3d4-489b-acf4-c6712c2c83ee%27'
```

This fails.  Note - if I use the same query for a user without a + sign in the issuerAssignedId it works fine.  Only when the issuerAssignedId has a + sign does the query fail.

```
curl --location 'https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?%24filter=identities%2Fany(a%3Ac%2FissuerAssignedId%20eq%20%27test%2Btest1%40gmail.com%27%20and%20a%2Fissuer%20eq%20%27B2CQAFORD.onmicrosoft.com%27)'
```

Comment: Does it fail the curl itself or does it fail on graph api side? what error does it return?

Comment: Turns out we need to URL encode the + symbol 2 times.  CarlZhao-MSFT assisted with the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out we have to double URL encode the + symbol.

Original: test+test1@gmail.com

1st encode: test%2Btest1@gmail.com

2nd encode: test%252Btest1@gmail.com